# Libreoffice not responsive / slow on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gtk, libreoffice

After a fresh install of Linux Mint on my system, Libreoffice feels slow and unresponsive. Every time I type something, there is a significant delay before the text comes up.

This is especially annoying on Calc, but Writer is affected too

Answer (score 1):

After digging around a bit, I found the delays are gone when libreoffice-gtk3 package is removed:

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice-gtk3
```

But then, libreoffice appearance is very poor.
I found that libreoffice-gtk2 package fixes both things: integrated looks and responsiveness:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk2
```

Or, simply

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk
```